# npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile as shown below, and when i execute it, I get a warning that i can't figure out in the `RUN npm ci` step:

> npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm

I tried `npm install` instead of `npm ci` and added the `--package-lock` flag, but I am still getting this warning. Is there a way to solve the watning? or should i ignore it?

```
Step 12/26 : RUN npm ci --production --package-lock &&     npm ci --production --package-lock --prefix ./ui-runner
 ---> Running in 3473c209b98c
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
```

Here is my *Dockerfile*.

```
FROM node:14.17.1-alpine3.13 AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
COPY ui-runner/package*.json ./ui-runner/
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY ui-runner/.npmrc ./ui-runner/.npmrc
RUN npm -g install npm@7.19.1
RUN npm ci --production --package-lock && \
    npm ci --production --package-lock --prefix ./ui-runner
RUN rm -f .npmrc && \
    rm -f ui-runner/.npmrc

FROM node:14.17.1-alpine3.13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl bash
RUN addgroup -g 1001 test && \
    adduser -S -u 1001 -G test test
RUN chown -R test /usr/src/app && \
    chmod 755 /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:docker
USER test
EXPOSE 3000 9183
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:ui-runner" ]
```

Answer (score 202):

There are several ways to deal with this. (People really seem to like #4.)

1. Ignore it. It's just a warning and does not affect the installation of modules.
2. Run `npm install --package-lock-only` (with the newer version of `npm`) to regenerate a `package-lock.json`. Commit the updated version of `package-lock.json` to the repo/Docker image or whatever.
3. Downgrade `npm` to an older version in production. Consider running `npm` version 6 as that is what ships with the current (as of this writing) Long Term Support (LTS) version of Node.js. In the case being asked about in this question, I imagine you can just leave out the `RUN npm -g install npm@7.19.1` from the Dockerfile and instead use the version of `npm` that is installed with the Docker image (which in this case will almost certainly be `npm@6` since that is what ships with Node.js 14.x).
4. If you already have a version of `npm` installed but want to run one command with an older version of `npm` but otherwise keep the newer version, you can use `npx` (which ships with `npm`) to do that. For example, `npx npm@6 ci` would run `npm ci` with `npm` version 6 even if you have version 7 installed.

Comment: I would like to thank you on #4. I have different NPM requirements for different projects and that command saved me a huge headache on the back and forth. It is interesting that you added it by saying it would probably not be useful here, but it is what saved me lol

Comment: @twocents What kind of documentation are you looking for? What part in the chain isn't making sense?

Comment: #4 should be a separated, accepted answer. <3

Answer (score 9):

An easy solution to this is to use [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage your node versions. Especially on Linux this saves a lot of trouble with file permissions, developing in different environments, etc.  NPM recommends this in their documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm).

This error for me was solved by switching Node.js versions with nvm,

```
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
```

It is always an easy thing to try and switch to a slightly older or newer Node.js version if you are running into weird Node.js or npm issues.

Comment: Node + Nvm ? ^^ are we not speeking about npm + npx ? ;)

Comment: @StéphaneM Node installed with Node Version Manager, npx commands still work with this setup.

Comment: The error isn't about node version but about npm version, just regenerate de package-lock with the newer version

Comment: @StéphaneM Node and NPM version are tied together right? You can either rebuild the package-lock with a different version of Node / NPM or just switch to the version of NPM that the project folder was last installed and built with.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem but upgrading npm  `npm i -g npm` on my machine before building the image solved it for me. You may still get the warn message but the image build process won't be halted.

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same problem as well after upgrading my npm version. It seems like a bug from npm 7.19.1, and I'd suggest to downgrade to an older version.

You can check below for all the npm versions

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm?activeTab=versions

Install the desired version with this command in the console, and substitute "V" with your desired version:

```
npm install -g npm@"V"
```

Comment: I'm getting something like this, too, and it tells me something about fixing the upstream dependency, but trying to install the version it says it expects give me an error and won't let me install it. I get an error like --C:\Users\jjones2\Downloads\rnn5-01-first-example\rnn5-01-first-example>npm install
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from expo-permissions@9.0.1
npm ERR! Could not resolve dep:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.11.0" from react-native@0.62.2

Comment: This is a Docker specific issue. Not sure how does your answer help the question

Comment: I had this issue happened to me on my windows environment, I don't use docker, it is an NPM specific issue, not Docker specific.

Comment: ^ also had this happen on my mac environment, not using Docker.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

As [Trott suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260784/npm-warn-old-lockfile-the-package-lock-json-file-was-created-with-an-old-version/68479189#68479189) it is totally fine to ignore the warning. To fix the warning/problem keep reading.

The problem/warning is with the line:

```
RUN npm -g install npm@7.19.1
```

Removing this line should fix the problem/warning.

**Explanation**

The package-lock generated which is part of your source repository *ideally* is generated with npm version < `npm@7` which ships with Node.js <= `node@14.x.x`. My guess comes from your first line of **Dockerfile**.

```
FROM node:14.17.1-alpine3.13 AS builder
```

For example Node.js LTS `v14.17.1` ships with `npm@6.14.13`. See the full release list [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

`npm@5`, `npm@6` generate `package-lock@v1`, which is now a legacy release as per this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json). And `npm@7` which is the latest release generates `package-lock@v2`. When you do: `npm -g install npm@7.19.1`. It overrides your existing `package-lock@v1` with `package-lock@v2` giving out the warning in the process.`

npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm`

The updated **Dockerfile** should look like this:

```
FROM node:14.17.1-alpine3.13 AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
COPY ui-runner/package*.json ./ui-runner/
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY ui-runner/.npmrc ./ui-runner/.npmrc
RUN npm ci --production --package-lock && \
    npm ci --production --package-lock --prefix ./ui-runner
RUN rm -f .npmrc && \
    rm -f ui-runner/.npmrc

FROM node:14.17.1-alpine3.13
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl bash
RUN addgroup -g 1001 test && \
    adduser -S -u 1001 -G test test
RUN chown -R test /usr/src/app && \
    chmod 755 /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:docker
USER test
EXPOSE 3000 9183
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:ui-runner" ]
```

Comment: What would cause this w/o Docker?

Comment: if your package-lock initially was generated with npm version < `npm@7`
and then you try to install packages with `npm@7`. you will get this warning

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue. After reading the previous comments, I noticed that the Node.js version installed on my machine was `v14.17.5` and the npm version was `v7.19.1`. Referring to [version history lookup](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) and downgrading npm to `v6.14.14` (compatible against node `v14.17.5`) resolved issue.

Answer (score 2):

First check for your Node.js version: Go to a cmd prompt and

```
node -v
```

Based on the version, check the *node-sass* version and install it:

```
npm node-sass@version
```

From *[node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)*:

```
Node 16  -  6.0+
Node 15  -  5.0+
Node 14  -  4.14+
Node 13  -  4.13+,
Node 12  -  4.12+
Node 11  -  4.10+,
Node 10  -  4.9+,
Node 8   -  4.5.3+,
Node <8  -  <5.0
```

Comment: I tried to reformat it to put as code only what's actually code.Please check if this reflects your intent now.

Comment: What system was this tested on? Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Strapi v4
I used:

1)

```
nvm use 16.15.1
```

(old was 14.X.X)

2)

```
npm rebuild
```

3. 

```
npm install
```

Seem to work now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it like this:

To resolve the warning:

> npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm

1. Run the `npm install --package-lock-only` command to resolve any conflicts and update your `package-lock.json` file.
2. Delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.
3. Install your modules with npm install.
4. Commit the updated `package-lock.json` file to your repository.

Comment: What's the reason to run npm install if you delete node_modules and package-lock.json?

Answer (score 0):

Step to resolve this issue
delete your node module
delete your package-lock.json file
run npm i
this will install the npm that were required in your project