# Node.js not compatible with react-create-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have node.js `14.6.0` and node-v `7.20.0`

Steps to reproduce:

1. `npx create-react-app my-app2`
2. once all is installed run `npm i`

Now you should get the following:

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.       
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
```

After this the terminal suggest `npm audit fix`

and when running that I get a list of errors the first one being:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While resolving: babel-loader@8.1.0 npm WARN Found: webpack@4.44.2 npm WARN node_modules/webpack npm WARN   peer webpack@">=4.43.0 <6.0.0" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3 npm WARN   node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin npm WARN     @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"0.4.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3 npm WARN     node_modules/react-scripts npm WARN   17 more (css-loader, eslint-webpack-plugin, file-loader, ...)
```

Is there a compatibility issue? what versions should I be using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260784/npm-warn-old-lockfile-the-package-lock-json-file-was-created-with-an-old-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those facing the same problem just :

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.12
```

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the package.lock.js file and for then run npm i

Comment: m8 thats one of the basic things. I did that a few times before posting

Comment: npm i create-react-app

Try this maybe ur running old version