# npm install problem. After every input it shows the same about some files missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

i m posting the output ..I can t understand anything please tell me what to do

> npm WARN old lockfile
> npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
> npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
> npm WARN old lockfile
> npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
> npm WARN old lockfile
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! path D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
> npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102 --python=python2.7 --msvs_version=2017' (1)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.1.0 | win32 | x64
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" (not found)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@17.1.0 (node-v102 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
> npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.1.0 | win32 | x64
> npm ERR! gyp info ok
> npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
> npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.1.0 | win32 | x64
> npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31911.196) found at:
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v102" "--python=python2.7" "--msvs_version=2017"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.1.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102 --python=python2.7 --msvs_version=2017' (1)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\nft\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_update\node_modules\canvas
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.1.0
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-10T15_29_35_648Z-debug.log

Comment: _"You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio"_

Comment: Deleting package-lock.json and generating it back by running "npm i"helped me!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260784/npm-warn-old-lockfile-the-package-lock-json-file-was-created-with-an-old-version)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

One of the packages makes use of node-gyp. Node-gyp is a library to build native-addons for nodejs, that are OS-specific (see [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp))

To fix these issue, you need to install Python and Visual Studio Build Tools on windows.

A "simple" method to do this, is to either install it directly via the node installer for windows, or use the npm package [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools)(the README also has a link to the node installer method).