# npm install not completing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

`npm install` not completing. Plase help me.

```
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
```

[my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/250dS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260784/npm-warn-old-lockfile-the-package-lock-json-file-was-created-with-an-old-version)

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error. As your screenshot says, be patient, it will finish at some point

Comment: I waited for 30 minutes for it to load but the installation did not complete

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**

Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and fresh install `npm install` with your new node.js version.

**Second Solution**

This issue facing the newest version of npm, so that I just downgrade to an older version and the error is solved. Just install the desired version with this command in the console, substitute “V” with your desired version.

```
 npm install -g npm@"V"
```

**Third Solution**

Just ignore this warning. It’s just a warning, and all that’s happening is npm is adding information to the `package-lock.json` file. I think this warning will be solved in the next version.

Read this for more information: [enter link description here](https://exerror.com/npm-warn-old-lockfile-the-package-lock-json-file-was-created-with-an-old-version-of-npm/)